# React Native app fails to login after running npm run android -- --mode="release"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm building a React Native app and I'm having trouble with login. I can build the app successfully using the command npm run android -- --mode="release", but when I try to login from the login screen, the app crashes.

I'm not sure what to ask

```
const handleLogin = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.1.77:89/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: username,
        password: password,
        expiresIn: '10s',
      }),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.status === 'ok') {
          console.log(data);
          console.log('Login success!');
          console.log('Token:', data.token);
          AsyncStorage.setItem('@accessToken', data.token);
          //const value = AsyncStorage.getItem('@accessToken');
          onPress();
        } else {
          console.log('Login failed:', data.message);
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('API Error:', error);
      });
  };
```

You can experiment with the app test api.